# Is it possible to upload/download memory from/to external files in Atmel Studio?

Tags: atmel-studio

In the old AVR Studio 4 there was an easy option to upload eepeom to the chip from an external file, and also to quickly download either the whole or a specified range of flash or eeprom or RAM memory and write it to an external file.

How is it possible to achieve something similar in the Atmel Studio 6, or in the current Atmel Studio 7?

While I'm in debug mode and need to upload a different eeprom file to the chip (while the EESAVE fuse is set, so I can keep the changes I did to the eerpom while testing), then I have to do the following tedious journey:

- stop debugging
- switch from debugwire to SPI
- edit the fuse settings (to disable eesave)
- edit the file containing the eeprom data in the project
- rebuild the project so the everything is written to the chip
- edit the fuse settings again (to enable eesave)
- start the debug session again (which will automatically recompile and re-burn everything again)

There is an [old forum thread](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/avr-studio-6-simulator-eeprom) from almost 3 years ago describing this problem, with a hint that the feature from AVR Studio 4 will soon be added.

Is there a simper approach to upload and download the eeprom in Atmel Studio 6? The above lengthy procedure is too impractical if I need it often, and it provides no possibility to just download part of the memory into a file to be analysed by some of my custom-built tools.

Is this really a feature that no one needs besides me?

Answer (score 2):

Check out `Tools-Device Programming`. That should bring up the following dialog...

[image]

...which lets you directly read/program the eeprom to/from a file.

Comment: This makes it a little bit more handy than rebuilding everything, but it still has two disadvantages: I can't just overwrite a specific range in the eeprom, and the chip must be in spi mode.